# How to find a string between to special characters in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings like this:

```
uc001acu.2;C1orf159;chr1:1046736-1056736;uc001act.2;C1orf159;
```

I need to extract the sub-string between two semicolons and I only need the first occurrence.

The result should be: `C1orf159`

I have tried this code, but it does not work:

```
import re
info = "uc001acu.2;C1orf159;chr1:1046736-1056736;uc001act.2;C1orf159;"
name = re.search(r'\;(.*)\;', info)
print name.group()
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split the string and limit it to two splits.

```
x = info.split(';',2)[1]
```

Comment: what is [1] for? I tried this, it gave me this error:list index out of range

Comment: @user1080814 you could try this `x = s.split(';')[1]` also.

Comment: if I try this : x = s.split(';')[0] then it does not give any error, but the result is :uc001acu.2 which is not correct.

Comment: There was a problem in the for loop that I was using to read string one by one, I debugged it and now every thing works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
       import re
       pattern=re.compile(r".*?;([a-zA-Z0-9]+);.*")
       print pattern.match(info).groups()
```

This looks for first  ;  eating up non greedily through  .*? .Then it captures the alpha numeric string until next ; is found.Then it eats up the rest of the string.Match captured though .groups()

Comment: I do not know why, but when I try this code, it gives me this error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: info="uc001acu.2;C1orf159;chr1:1046736-1056736;uc001act.2;C1orf159" You do give this right.

Comment: yes, the string is correct, but it give an error that "groups" is not an attribute!

Comment: i have python 2.7 .its working fine there.There should not be any problems. :(

Comment: As currently, this answer is listed as low quality. If possible, explain what this code does; the regex, and the function.